# Why are pointwise and uniform convergences topologizable?

Tags: general-topology

My question is about two types of convergence on functional spaces.

- Why can pointwise convergence for mappings from a set to a topological space be topologizable?
- Why can uniform convergence for mappings from a topological space to a uniform space be topologizable?

If I understand correctly, "topologizable" means there exists a topology, s.t. the given convergence is the same as the convergence wrt the topology.

For example, for uniform convergence, [here](https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Topology_of_uniform_convergence) it's topology, actually its uniform structure, is provided explicitly.

I am wondering if there is some way to tell if a certain type of convergence is topologizable without constructing the topology, and if there is a general way to find such topology?

Thanks and regards!

Comment: Sorry about ny question, but is there a definition of convergence of a sequence that's not assume a topology first?

Comment: @Tomás: the preassumed topologies are those on the domain space and the codomain space of the mappings, not the one on the set of such mappings. It is the existence of the topology on the set of such mappings that my post is asking for.

Comment: I think that my question still valid for this set too. How do you talk about uniform convergence without a topology? What is the definition?

Comment: the convergences are defined as what you have learned before. Nothing special.

Comment: Well, what type of convergence do you have in mind? [Moore–Smith](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Net_%28mathematics%29), [filter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filter_%28mathematics%29), or sequence convergence? And do you have problems with some specific definition of uniform or pointwise convergence? I ask because the definitions of the corresponding topologies seem quite straightforward to me, it being textbook material and all. Without knowing your background, it is difficult to give a helpful answer.

Comment: @Harald: I have the definitions for pointwise convergence for mappings from a set to a topologicalspace, and uniform convergence for mappings from a topological space to a uniform space. Why are these convergences topologizable? For example, for [uniform convergence](http://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Topology_of_uniform_convergence) it's topology, actually its uniform structure, is provided explicitly. I am wondering if there is some way to tell if a certain type of convergence is topologizable without constructing the topology, and if there is a general way to find such topology?

Comment: @HaraldHanche-Olsen: I am also trying to learn if a given type of convergence is topologizable and how to construct its topology, [in general](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/311984/what-tools-are-used-to-show-a-type-of-convergence-is-or-is-not-topologizable). Other examples are various convergences of measures and of measurable mappings.

Comment: Ah, you should have given a reference to that other question of yours before; then this one would have been much less bewildering. You can't assume that people read every question here! I certainly can't keep up. Anyway, I still find your question difficult to answer, because it has a trivial answer which I don't think will satisfy you: These convergences are topologizable because we can in fact exhibit the topologies which implement the convergences. I think you question is either very good or very bad, and I can't make up my mind either way.

Comment: @Harald: Thanks! I have asked a lot of questions, and many of them are pretty "bad". :-)

Comment: You may be interested in "convergence spaces" (e.g. the book "Convergence Structures and Applications to Functional Analysis" by Beattie and Butzmann and may also want to look up "sequential spaces".

Comment: @Dirk: Thanks! I have been searching for that book on internet. I guess it is a good one too.