# relationship between topology and convergences

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis

In my textbook, the topology of $C_c^\infty$ and $C^\infty$ are defined by: how $f_n\to f$ in these topologies. Similarly, the weak-* topology are also defined by the same manner.

I wonder why we can determine a topology only by convergent sequence since topology ought to be defined by open sets?

Comment: Generally, speaking topologies are uniquely determined by convergence of $\textit{nets}$. Sequences are not generally enough to uniquely determine the topology, though they are if the topology is first countable, I think. More specifically to your question though, the way that the convergence is defined in this case, you would easily write out a subbasis of open sets and then get the topology from there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What Owen said is correct.  It is *not* sufficient to specify a topology by defining what it means for sequences to converge.  For example, the discrete topology and the cocountable topology on $\mathbb{R}$ yield nonhomeomorphic spaces, but their notions of sequential convergence are the same:  a sequence converges iff it is eventually constant.

In practice, when defining topologies in this way, the definition of convergence you want to make for sequences still makes sense if you replace the word "sequence" with the word "net", and so fixing this is quite easy.  In particular, in your case, if you replace the word "sequence" with the word "net", there should be a unique topology on $C_c^{\infty}$ and $C^{\infty}$ whose notion of convergence agrees with your given condition.

Of course, you can't just make any old definition of convergence.  In order for it to define a topology, your definition has to satisfy a list of axioms---see, for example, Theorem 3.4.8 on pg. 105 [here](https://www.academia.edu/15037429/Introduction_to_Analysis) (note that if you're reading this in the future, these numbers may have changed).  This theorem gives the precise formulation of how one may define topologies by declaring what it means for nets to converge.

Comment: @user166445: Another list of axioms can be found in Kelley’s *General Topology*, p. $74$; they are more conveniently accessible in [this MSE question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/311980/relation-between-convergence-class-and-convergence-space).

Comment: @BrianM.Scott thanks a lot!

Comment: @user166445: My pleasure!

Comment: They should be essentially the same axioms.  Indeed, my source for this was Kelley itself.  Perhaps I reworded things in a way that I found easier to understand, but, unless I made a mistake, the mathematical content should be the same.